# a generalization of group (monoid with order-by-order invertible elements)

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, local-rings

Fix a filtered monoid, $H=H_0\supsetneq H_1\supsetneq H_2\supsetneq\cdots$. Suppose for any $h\in H$ and any $n\in \Bbb{N}$ exists $h_n\in H$ such that $h\cdot h_n\in H_n$ and $h_n\cdot h\in H_n$. If a filtration stabilizes at a finite step to the identity element, then $H$ is a group. In many cases the filtration is infinite, so $H$ is not necessarily a group, and yet close to being a group.

Examples:

1. Let $R=k[x]\supset (x)\supset (x^2)\supset\cdots$. The elements of $1+(x)$ are order-by-order invertible. If $R$ were local, the elements would be invertible.
2. $H=\{A|\ det(A)\in \{1\}+(x)\}\subset Mat_{n\times n}(R)$. If $R$ were local this would be a subgroup of $GL(n,R)$.

What is the standard name for such "almost groups"? Some references?

([asked this question on stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657077/a-generalization-of-group-monoid-with-order-by-order-invertible-elements), no reply)

Comment: To clarify: In Example 1, you want $H_n = 1 + (x^n)$, right?

Comment: @neil-epstein :  right

Comment: I don't know.  But I guess you could restate the condition to say that you have a filtered monoid such that $H_j / H_{j+1}$ is a group for all $j$.  Interesting condition.  Definitely a new one to me.

Comment: Such structures appear naturally in Singularity Theory, Local Geometry, Comm.Alg. over local rings. (In some cases Nakayama turns them into ordinary groups.) I would expect these to be well known, axiomatized, text-booked.  :(